# Akka Play guice bindings tagless final (TF) support

Tags: scala, akka, guice, tagless-final

I have this binding to configure the Logger[IO] in my app (module with this line is in guice.conf file):

```scala
class CatsEffectModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {

  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind[Logger[IO]].toInstance(Slf4jLogger.getLogger[IO])
  }

}
```

Then in the app i can do this:

```scala
@Singleton
class MyClass @Inject()(implicit logger: Logger[IO]) { ... }
```

And this works fine in the application.

But it won't work when used in `GuiceInjectorBuilder` (for tests):

```scala
import play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjectorBuilder


private val application: Injector = new GuiceInjectorBuilder()
    .bindings(bind[ExecutionContext].to(ExecutionContext.global))
    .bindings(bind[ApplicationLifecycle].to[DefaultApplicationLifecycle])
    .bindings(new CatsEffectModule())
    .build()

application.instanceOf[MyClass]
```

It gives me an error:

```
No implementation for io.chrisdavenport.log4cats.Logger was bound.
[info]   Did you mean?
[info]     io.chrisdavenport.log4cats.Logger<cats.effect.IO> bound  at guice.CatsEffectModule.configure(CatsEffectModule.scala:21) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> guice.CatsEffectModule)
```

And every TF-entity injection in tests fails like this. Is there some difference between how Akka Play runs Guice and how GuiceInjectorBuilder works?

Code example: https://github.com/DenisNovac/play-tf-test

Comment: I think you can try this application.injector.instanceOf[CatsEffectModule]

Comment: @ShwetaValunj it is already an injector. `build()` just calls `injector()` under the cape. Also i guess i don't need an instance of CatsEffectModule. It only contains some other binds. Even if i copy them in tests it won't work (i tried).

Comment: Ahh. I just noticed the builder. Have you tried to use GuiceOneAppPerSuite from org.scalatestplus.play.guice ?

Comment: As far as i know it uses `GuiceApplicationBuilder` which starts up all the modules from `guice.conf`. I am using `GuiceInjectorBuilder` because i want only one module. Perhaps it will work (since it will follow the same logic as starting the app), but i need to get it work with `GuiceInjectorBuilder`.

Comment: I've added example repo url at the question. After the rewriting i noticed that we are using  some custom `AbstractModule` wrapper - `ScalaModule`. But still it is used in tests too while constructing the guice builder.

Comment: I guess, it is `ScalaModule` by codingwell which makes it work for the app. So the default GuiceInjectorBuilder's `bind` function won't work (example: https://github.com/DenisNovac/play-tf-test/blob/master/test/controllers/HomeControllerSpec.scala#L26)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Scala-guice by codingwell (https://github.com/codingwell/scala-guice) allows to bind TF-classes (it is made for vanilla Guice, not the Play Guice). They will be binded to dependent classes correctly, but the `GuiceInjectorBuilder` won't let you get it by `instanceOf` method.

But it seems that it works in both directions if you use both binds:

```scala
import cats.effect.IO
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import net.codingwell.scalaguice.ScalaModule
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers
import play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjectorBuilder
import play.api.inject.{ApplicationLifecycle, DefaultApplicationLifecycle, Injector, bind}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

class WorkingModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {

  override def configure(): Unit =
    bind[CustomTFInterface[IO]].toInstance(new CustomTFInterfaceImpl)
}

class HomeControllerSpec extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers {

  it should "test1" in {
    val application: Injector = new GuiceInjectorBuilder()
      .bindings(bind[ExecutionContext].to(ExecutionContext.global))
      .bindings(bind[ApplicationLifecycle].to[DefaultApplicationLifecycle])
      .bindings(bind[CustomTFInterface[IO]].toInstance(new CustomTFInterfaceImpl))
      .bindings(new CatsEffectModule())
      .injector()

    application.instanceOf[CustomTFInterface[IO]] // works
    //application.instanceOf[InjecableWithTfDependencies] // fails

  }

  it should "test2" in {
    val application: Injector = new GuiceInjectorBuilder()
      .bindings(bind[ExecutionContext].to(ExecutionContext.global))
      .bindings(bind[ApplicationLifecycle].to[DefaultApplicationLifecycle])
      .bindings(new WorkingModule())
      .bindings(new CatsEffectModule())
      .injector()

    //application.instanceOf[CustomTFInterface[IO]] // fails
    application.instanceOf[InjecableWithTfDependencies] // works
  }

  it should "test3" in {
    val application: Injector = new GuiceInjectorBuilder()
      .bindings(bind[ExecutionContext].to(ExecutionContext.global))
      .bindings(bind[ApplicationLifecycle].to[DefaultApplicationLifecycle])
      // both binds together also works
      .bindings(new WorkingModule())
      .bindings(bind[CustomTFInterface[IO]].toInstance(new CustomTFInterfaceImpl))
      .bindings(new CatsEffectModule())
      .injector()

    application.instanceOf[CustomTFInterface[IO]]       // works
    application.instanceOf[InjecableWithTfDependencies] // works
  }

}
```

Perhaps there is a way to make scala-guice and play work together but i got no luck with it.

Full example: https://github.com/DenisNovac/play-tf-test